# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. The statement has been terminated

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I do not know why it doesn't show the form?

```
 public static void Rezervacija(int voziloId, int kupacId)
  {
    SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        konekcija.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
        konekcija.Open();

        string insertUpit = "INSERT INTO Iznajmljivanje(VoziloId, KupacId) "
                            + "VALUES(@VoziloId, @KupacId) ";

        SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand(insertUpit, konekcija);
        komanda.Parameters.Add("@VoziloId",voziloId);
        komanda.Parameters.Add("@KupacId", kupacId);

        komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        konekcija.Close();
    }
}
```

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Iznajmljivanje_Kupac". The conflict occurred in database ... table "dbo.Kupac", column 'KupacId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You are trying to insert a value that doesn't exist in the table referred to by the foreign key constraint.  It is a little hard to say more, without knowing the table definitions or contents.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to insert a value in the `KupacId` column which does not exist as a key in `dbo.Kupac` and there is a foreign key constraint on this relationship

This means that the value has to exist in `dbo.Kupac` (in I assume the `Id` column) if you want to insert it into `Iznajmljivanje.KupacId`

Comment: I dont know how to fix it? Yes in Iznajmljivanje have KupacId

Comment: @user1798078 for `KupacId` column, choose values which exists in `dbo.Kupac` table.

Comment: @user1798078 I am sorry  my friend, without seeing what you are trying to insert and what data is in the table, I cannot help you. It is not a code problem, it is a data issue.

Comment: Ok i'm resolve this my code is past. But not show me values in my gridview Rezervacija.

SELECT Kupac.Ime + ' ' + Kupac.Prezime AS PunoIme, Kupac.IdentifikacioniBroj, Vozilo.Marka, Vozilo.Model, Vozilo.RegistarskiBroj, Vozilo.Izdato, Iznajmljivanje.IznajmljivanjeId 
FROM Iznajmljivanje 
INNER JOIN Kupac ON Iznajmljivanje.KupacId = Kupac.KupacId 
INNER JOIN Vozilo ON Iznajmljivanje.VoziloId = Vozilo.VoziloId 
WHERE (Iznajmljivanje.DatumIznajmljivanja IS NULL)